# Ender 5 pro , prints lean, but only when multiple parts are printed (almost)

Tags: ultimaker-cura, creality-ender-5

[image: Lean in the +Y]I can print single, large, complex parts with multiple towers with long travels between them and nothing leans. So pretty sure it is not belt tension, lash, or slop.

When I add a second part to the build plate, there will be leaning. It starts leaning with the very first layers.
When I print the same parts one at a time and they do not lean.
(notable exception) If I add 2 parts to the plate, and then delete the first, and print just the second, it leans.

Any suggestions on how to move forward from here? I am stumped.

Comment: Could you add a picture, I'm not sure what is meant with leaning.

Comment: I have also found that the lean is affected by infill % A solid part Skews more than a hollow one. The solo part test prints all looked good because they were low infill, and adding a second part doubles the printed area AND THE SKEW. Adding a second part and using 100% infill makes a very stark difference. And the Enter key should not post the comment, it is meant as a CR LF, This is my opinion, not yours, though I am willing to share. Pressing the enter key here--->

Comment: Comments can not have more than one line, the Enter to end a comment is the intended behavior. You have 5 minutes to edit comments.

Comment: Thanks Trish. Still 100% my opinion that an enter key on a text box should not post. You don't need to share my opinion. ( Or my dry sense of humor) 



Interface design is complicated and hard to implement well. Typing a sentence and having the enter key POST the sentence is (in my very uninformed opinion) counterintuitive and wrong. 

One should be able to use white space...


It gives the writer more tools to express and accentuate ideas.

Comment: To accentuate, you can use `code`, *italic* or **bold**. You can even ***`combine all`***. :-) Welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! Note that comments are used for other people to ask for clarifications, you then try to address that in the question. SE sites are not regular threaded message forums, just simple Q and A.